# Ellipse Texture not doing what is expected

Tags: c#, math, textures, monogame, ellipse

I am generating dynamic textures in monogame for simple shapes. Yes I know the disadvantages to this system, but I am just experimenting with building my own physics engine. I am trying to generate the texture for an ellipse as is described [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bd80w8mtfv).

I have a function PaintDescriptor that takes an x and y pixel coordinate and gives back what color it should be. Red is just while I am debugging, and normally it would be Color.Transparent.

```cs
public override Color PaintDescriptor(int x, int y)
{
      float c = (float)Width / 2;
      float d = (float)Height / 2;
      return pow((x - c) / c, 2) + pow((y - d) / d, 2) <= 1 ? BackgroundColor : Color.Red;
}
```

Now this works if Width == Height, so, a circle. However, if they are not equal, it generates a texture with some ellipse like shapes, but also with banding/striping.

[image: normal circle][image: banding][image: striping]

I have tried seeing if my width and height were switched, and ive tried several other things. One thing to note is that where in the normal coordinate system on desmos I have (y + d) / d, but since the screen's y axis is flipped, I have to flip the y offset in the code: (y - d) / d. The rest of the relating code for texture generation and drawing is here:

```cs
public Texture2D GenerateTexture(GraphicsDevice device, Func<int, int, Color> paint)
{
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(device, Width, Height);

    Color[] data = new Color[Width * Height];

    for (int pixel = 0; pixel < data.Count(); pixel++)
        data[pixel] = paint(pixel / Width, pixel % Height);

    texture.SetData(data);

    return texture;
}

public void Draw(float scale = 1, float layerdepth = 0, SpriteEffects se = SpriteEffects.None)
{
    if (SBRef == null)
        throw new Exception("No reference to spritebatch object");

    SBRef.Draw(Texture, new Vector2(X, Y), null, null, null, 0, new Vector2(scale, scale), Color.White, se, layerdepth);
}

public float pow(float num, float power) //this is a redirect of math.pow to make code shorter and more readable
{
    return (float)Math.Pow(num, power);
}
```

Why doesnt this match desmos? Why does it not make an ellipse?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, but one possible solution I have come across is to always draw a circle, and then scale it to the desired width and height. This is not acceptable for me for one because of some possible blurriness in drawing, or other artifacts, but more mainly because I want to understand whatever im not currently getting with this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping and coming back with a fresh mindset for like the 10th time, I found the answer. in the function GenerateTexture:

```
data[pixel] = paint(pixel / Width, pixel % Height);
```

should be

```
data[pixel] = paint(pixel % Width, pixel / Height);
```